# Magento 2 show shipping according to categories

Tags: magento2.3, category, shipping-methods, ups, usps

**Is there a way or it is possible like this -**

**Suppose** 2 categories Category A and Category B

**Category A products have always shipping with USPS and inside further conditions -**

1 - If the order total price is less than $25 then show USPS -

USPS First Class mail letter & USPS First class mail postcards

2 - If order total price is greater than $25 then show USPS -

USPS Priority mail hold for pickup & USPS Priority mail smallflat rate box

**Category B products have always shipping with UPS and inside further conditions -**

1 - If the order total price is less than $25 then show UPS -

UPS standard & UPS Ground

2 - If the order total price is greater than $25 then show UPS -

UPS next day air & UPS second day air.